# Shell script hide console messages?

Tags: shell, scripting

I am having a really hard time hiding console messages from my shells (ksh) script which I run in the background.

I have tried moving it to /dev/null but it doesn't seem to be working.  Here is the line in the script:

```
pid=`/usr/local/bin/lsof | grep 16752 | grep LISTEN |awk '{print $2}'` > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Example after I have kicked off the script:

```
$ lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.

$ ls -lsof: WARNING: /home2/s499929/.lsof_ktazd2250 was updated.
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/lsof 2>/dev/null | grep 16752 | grep LISTEN |awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to redirect output of the actual lsof command and not awk?

Comment: Could you give me an example fulhack?

Comment: I was thinking something like this: `ls -ö 2>&1 | wc -l > dump 2>&1` the ö is there to make ls produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting the output of the variable assignment.  Since variable assignments don't produce any output, your redirection isn't doing anything.

The backticks capture the command's stdout; you need to redirect that command's stderr, which means the redirection needs to be between the backticks.

My first thought was to do this:

```
pid=`/usr/local/bin/lsof | grep 16752 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' 2>/dev/null`
```

but that only redirects the stderr of the `awk` command.  You need to discard stderr of the entire pipeline:

```
pid=`(/usr/local/bin/lsof | grep 16752 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}') 2>/dev/null`
```

But personally I prefer `$(...)` to backticks:

```
pid=$((/usr/local/bin/lsof | grep 16752 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}') 2>/dev/null)
```

(Note that I'm only redirecting stderr, not stdout; you need stdout for the variable assignment.)